# Covert JSON headers and rows to Object keys in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, api

I am getting the data from API in JSON format in Node JS . But JSON has headers and rows format data(screenshot also attached). It contains the data "Vendor , Price , SKU , Error". I want to put this data to like below Object . Where I can access any of these with Keys in the loop. e.g (product.Price)[image]

```
enter code here

let new_products = {
  product: {
    Vendor: String,
    Price: String,
    SKU: String,
    error: String
  }
};

I tried the many solutions and get one solution is working but its giving the whole data in one row not in the separate variable.[![enter image description here][2]][2]. The below is the code.

const request = require('request');
const { json } = require('express');
const { Parser } = require('json2csv');

let new_products = {
  product: {
    Vendor: String,
    Price: String,
    SKU: String,
    error: String
  }
};

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.dexi.io/runs/f58f7795-c11a-478c-b670-c7ae5df8677b/latest/result',
  headers: {
    accept: 'application/json',
    json: true,
    'x-dexiio-access': '9d56ee1281967df725exxxxxxxxxxx',
    'x-dexiio-account': '5e597fexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  var JSONdata = JSON.stringify(body);
  pro = JSON.parse(body);
  product = pro.json;

for(var key in pro) {
  for(var innerKey in pro[key]) {
    console.log("Key: " + innerKey + " value: " + pro[key][innerKey]);
 }      
}
});
```

My purpose to format the API data in the object to access with key and index. Please help me in this regard. Help will be grateful for me.

Thanks

Comment: I see that you JSON.stringify, followed by JSON.parse. Is there a reason for this? What do you get when you omit both? What happens when you omit only JSON.stringify(body)?

Comment: No there is not any specific reason. I was just checking with different ways to get the results

Answer (score 0):

Trying to change your code with the following:

```
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw Error(error);
  let JSONdata = JSON.parse(body);


  console.log(typeof JSONdata); // JSONdata is an object, so you can start to manipulate it
  console.log(JSONdata); // show in console the object

  for (var key in JSONdata) {
    for (var innerKey in JSONdata[key]) {
      console.log("Key: " + innerKey + " value: " + JSONdata[key][innerKey]);
    }
  }
});
```

I posted an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-flower-hz2j9?file=/src/index.js:512-909) in CodeSandbox

From MDN doc:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

*The JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string*

I hope I have helped you.

Comment: Thanks @Nicola Lanzoni I tried this method before but got the solution to get it with Keys like Price , SKU etc with                                                                                             
products = []
pro.rows.forEach(
    row => { let product = {};
        for (let z = 0; z < row.length; z++) 
        {
            product[pro.headers[z]] = row[z]
           // console.log(row[z])
        }
        products.push(product)
       // console.log(product.SKU)
            }
);